# C# MODBUS RTU for REGISTER READING

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus, serial-communication

I am currently in the process of writing a c# program in VS where it reads the holding registers of a Panasonic KW9M-A Power Meter using Modbus-RTU. The holding register i'm trying to read is:
00A4H to 00A5H; Unsigned 32bit

Note: I wrote this in Console app. I used NModbus4 by Maxwe11
Idk what i'm missing since i'm a beginner in programming. Can someone please assist me? Thank you in advance :)

Here is what i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console_ye
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM13", 115200, Parity.Odd, 8, StopBits.One);
            serialPort.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("This is the beginning: ");

            string hex_add = "0x00A4";
            ushort dec_add = Convert.ToUInt16(hex_add, 16);

            Console.WriteLine("Value of hex: " + hex_add);
            Console.WriteLine("Value of ushort: " + dec_add);

            byte slaveId = 1;
            ushort startAddress = dec_add;
            ushort numberOfPoints = 8;
            IModbusMaster masterRTU = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu (serialPort);
            ushort[] ushortArray = masterRTU.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numberOfPoints);

            Console.WriteLine("Here " + ushortArray[0]);
            foreach (ushort item in ushortArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join ("\n", item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe Modbus is built into C#, so you are probably missing a `using` statement and maybe a reference. Are you getting an error? If so , please add it to your question.

Comment: Modbus is a serial protocol, you must follow the protocol or the device listening with modbus won't understand you.  There are several different Modbus protocols so you'll need to use the right one (ASCII, RTU, TCP/IP, etc).  I have no idea what `IModbusMaster` is, your best bet is to follow the documentation for their library.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about NModbus4, but as shown in the [sample program](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4/blob/portable-3.0/Samples/Program.cs), you'll probably need to include one or more of the following in your program.

```
using Modbus.Data;
using Modbus.Device;
using Modbus.Utility;
using Modbus.Serial;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the line:
`Console.WriteLine(string.Join ("\n", item));`
to
`Console.WriteLine(item);`

Then it'll be workable.

Comment: This answer does not address the question asked.